# .Htaccess Not working with CSS and JS

Tags: .htaccess

This is my original Url: index.php?page=aboutus and then i coverted to like this: index/page/aboutus

Question is: why CSS and JS not working?

**Edit:** Current `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php
RewriteRule page/(.*) index.php?page=$1
#fix css, js, image links
RewriteRule ^index/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Show your htaccess code, please.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php

RewriteRule page/(.*) index.php?page=$1

# fix css, js, image links
RewriteRule ^index/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [NC,L]

Comment: I have added your code to the question - please edit the question future as commenting does not preserve line breaks. Regarding your issue, you are more than likely not using root-relative references in your HTML. You would need to ensure that your CSS links have leading slashes (`/my/styles.css` instead of `my/styles.css`) to ensure they are loaded relative to the root of your site. Alternatively, you can add `<base href="/">` to the `<head>` of your HTML

Comment: If you do that, you can remove the last rule in your `.htaccess` file - that would become redundant (not needed).

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer but it's no working for my problem.

Comment: So what does "not working" mean then? Are you getting errors? Is the CSS and JS just not loading? Did you check your Network tab in the browser Developer Tools?